# Javascript remoting not working in offline mode.Error says "Visualforce is not defined"

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, visualforce, apex, html5-appcache

I am using Javascript remoting in our application. We also have offline functionality of HTML5 cache menifest in the application. Our application flow is such that whenever a user is online all the files including javascript files are cached and stored in local storage and all the process is done using these files either online or offline.

My issue is, As we are using files from the cache Visualforce object of Javascript remoting is not created(as it is created on server). However, we are unable execute any soql query.

Error says "Visualforce is not defined".

How can we solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without see your code, but at some point the Visualforce object is being executed while it's undefined. The Visualforce object should only be used when you are making a remoting call. If you are offline, you obviously can't make a remoting call to the server.

You could start by setting an cachedPageLoad variable if Visualforce is not defined:

```
if(!Visualforce) {
  cachedPageLoad = true;
} else {
  cachedPageLoad = false
}
```

Then nest all of your Visualforce.remoting calls inside a check of the cachedPageLoad variable.

```
if(cachedPageLoad) {
  // save to local storage
} else {
  // Visualforce.remoting call
}
```